# Stop mongoose from interpret string as (hex) number

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, hex

I have stored crypto account addresses in mongodb, and want to retrieve documents using the addresses. One example look like this "0x754B2f9797b096f417a24686c4B368F508...". My schema specify the addresses are string, and thus, the addresses are stored in mongodb in string and look as the above example. I can retrieve document as expected in mongosh (shell). However, I cannot retrieve any document even if I pass literal string in the filter with mongoose (using find, findOne, and so on). The only way to retrive documents is to not pass any filter. I guess mongoose interprets the value as number and thus convert it before pass to mongodb.
How can I fix the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: could you add sample data ?